# Are Ashtamurti Swarupa, 11 Rudras, Pancha brahma shiva, Ashta(8) Bhairavas important in trika shaivism

Tags: vedas, shiva, tantra, kashmiri-shaivism

Please give a detailed account of trika beliefs regarding ishwara gita and shiva gita too. Currently I have assimilated some verses from shaiva upanishads and vedas,aranyaka and samhitas in my prayers is it ok . I know shri acharya abhinavgupta has spoken about ashtamurti shiva but I want a clear answer to this query. By the way I read shiv sutras of vasugupta too.

Comment: Abhinavagupta in Tantrasara talks about performing nyasa in Ashtamurti forms of Lord Shiva.. in places he also quotes verses from Upanishads and Vedas...

Comment: @Tezz Thank you for replying but can I read ishwara gita too . Is it ok to be in trika shaivism and read ishwara and shiva gita

Comment: @Tezz can you give transliteration of those passages. I will be grateful

Comment: In my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21725/what-are-the-eight-forms-ashtamurti-of-lord-shiva/21728#21728), you can find it under title **AshtaMurti description in various stotras/works**. Yes, it is okay to read Ishwara Gita and Shiva Gita.. Trika Shaivism also uses term like Shiva, Pashupati, Parameshwara, etc... which are used in Ishwara and Shiva Gita... Moreover the foundation that 'Lord Shiva is everything, he has five actions (creation, protection, destruction, veiling and grace) come from Sri Rudram of Yajurveda itself which is accepted by Trika. @Christopher

Comment: @Tezz Thank you sir. Your answer is very enlightening. Can you help with other question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48985/for-lay-followers-can-you-give-beautiful-verses-which-shows-greatness-of-lord-sh