# For Lay Followers can you give beautiful verses which shows greatness of lord shiva in ishwara and shiva gita . English translation &transliteration

Tags: shiva, puranas, shaivism

Verses which denotes power, universal form, beauty, greatness and might of shiva

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question.

Comment: @Wikash_ Seriously bro, this cracked me up.  Is it because he forgot the question mark?

Answer (score 3):

[Shiva Geeta Chapter 6: Vibhooti Yoga](http://www.mahapashupatastra.com/2010/05/shiva-gita-ch-06-vibhooti-yoga.html)

Verses 10 - 60

> अथ तेऽपहृतज्ञआना मामाहुः को भवानिति .
> अथाब्रुवमहं देवानहमेव पुरातनः [10]
> After assembling there, they stood near the mount Mandara with folded hands and sang hymns in my praise. Knowing their desire, out of playful mood i had stolen away their knowledge. Then when I appeared, under ths stupor of ignorance, the question me "Who are you?". In that context i addressed them and said: O gods! I'm the Adi-Anadi-Purusha (oldest primordial being).

आसं प्रथममेवाहं वर्तामि च सुरेश्वराः .
भविष्यामि च लोकेऽस्मिन्मत्तो नान्यस्ति कश्चन [11]
व्यतिरिक्तं च मत्तोऽस्ति नान्यत्किञ्चित्सुरेश्वराः .
नित्योऽनित्योऽहमनघो ब्रह्मणां ब्रह्मणस्पतिः [12]
दक्षिणाञ्च उदञ्चोऽहं प्राञ्चः प्रत्यञ्च एव च .
अधश्चोर्ध्वं च विदिशो दिशश्चाहं सुरेश्वराः [13]
सावित्री चापि गायत्री स्त्री पुमानपुमानपि .
त्रिष्टुब्जगत्यनुष्टुप च पंक्तिश्छन्दस्त्रयीमयः [14]
सत्योऽहं सर्वगः शान्तस्त्रेताग्निर्गौर्यहं गुरुः .
गौर्यहं गह्वरं चाहं द्यौरहं जगतां विभुः [15]
ज्येष्ठः सर्वसुरश्रेष्ठो वरिष्ठोऽहमपांपतिः .
आर्योऽहं भगवानीशस्तेजोऽहं चादिरप्यहम [16]
ऋग्वेदोऽहं यजुर्वेदः सामवेदोऽहमात्मभूः .
अथर्वणश्च मन्त्रोऽहं तथा चाङ्गिरसो वरः [17]
इतिहासपुराणानि कल्पोऽहं कल्पवानहम .
नाराशंसी च गाथाहं विद्योपनिषदोऽस्म्यहम [18]
श्लोकाः सूत्राणि चैवाहमनुव्याख्यानमेव च .
व्याख्यानानि परा विद्या इष्टं हुतमथाहुतिः [19]
दत्तादत्तमयं लोकः परलोकऽहमक्षरः .
क्षरः सर्वाणि भूतानि दान्तिः शान्तिरहं खगः [20]
गुह्योऽहं सर्ववेदेषु आरण्योहमजोऽप्यहम .
पुष्करं च पवित्रं च मध्यं चाहमतः परम [21]
बहिश्चाहं तथा चान्तः पुरस्तादहमव्ययः .
ज्योतिश्चाहं तमश्चाहं तन्मात्राणीन्द्रियाण्यहम [22]
बुद्धिश्चाहमहंकारो विषयाण्यहमेव हि .
ब्रह्मा विष्णुर्महेशोहमुमा स्कन्दो विनायकः [23]
इन्द्रोऽग्निश्च यमश्चाहं निरृतिर्वरुणोऽनिलः .
कुबेरोऽहं तथेशानो भूर्भुवः स्वर्महर्जनः [24]
तपः सत्यं च पृथिवी चापस्तेजोऽनिलोऽप्यहम .
आकाशोऽहं रविः सोमो नक्षत्राणि ग्रहास्तथा [25]
प्राणः कालस्तथा मृत्युरमृतं भूतमप्यहम .
भव्यं भविष्यत्कृत्स्नं च विश्वं सर्वात्मकोऽप्यहम [26]
O deities! Know that in this entire universe, there is none other than me. I'm the non-dual one. I'm the ancient one. I'm the one who is eternal and I'm the non-eternal too, I'm the one who is blemishless (sinless). I'm the one called as Brahmanaspati. I'm all the directions. I'm savitri, I'm Gayatri. All these male, female and eunuchs also are me. I'm the Thrishtup, Jagati, Anushthup, Pankti chandas. I'm the one known through Vedas, I'm the truth, I'm peace, and I'm respect. I'm the lord of the universe, I'm the oldest, I'm the lord of all, I'm the Bhagawan (supreme personality of godhead), I'm the Lord, I'm the divine light. I'm the Itihasa, and Purana. I'm the Kalpa (eon), I'm the Upa-Kalpa (manvantara), I'm the one who create these Kalpas, I'm the knowledge, I'm in the hymns of Upanishads, I'm mantra, and I'm the Vyakhyana (commentary) also. I'm the sacrificial offerings, I'm the donor, I'm the donation, I'm Ihaloka (this material world where jiva takes birth), I'm Paraloka (world where Jiva goes after departure), I'm Akshara (imperishable) and I'm kshara (perishable) too, I'm all these creatures. Self-control, serenity, and secrecy are also me. I'm the one having faces everywhere. I'm the end, and middle, I'm the door, I'm outside, i'm inside, I'm the front and back as well. I'm the imperishable one. I'm light and also i'm darkness, I'm the Indriyas (organs) and the Tanmatras as well. I'm the mind, intellect and ego. I'm the Vishayas (subjects) also. I'm Brahma, I'm Vishnu, I'm Maheshwara, I'm Uma, I'm Skanda, I'm Vinayaka. I'm Indra, Agni and Yama also. I'm Nairuti, varuna and Vayo (anil). I'm Kubera, I'm the fourteen worlds. I'm the Sun, I'm the moon, I'm stars and planets as well, I'm all these creatures, I'm the Prana(soul), I'm the time, death, and eternity. I'm the past, present and future. I'm everything indeed!

ओमादौ च तथा मध्ये भूर्भुवः स्वस्तथैव च .
ततोऽहं विश्वरूपोऽस्मि शीर्षं च जपतां सदा [27]
अशितं पायितं चाहं कृतं चाकृतमप्यहम .
परं चैवापरं चाहमहं सर्वपरायणः [28]
अहं जगद्धितं दिव्यमक्षरं सूक्ष्ममव्ययम .
प्राजापत्यं पवित्रं च सौम्यमग्राह्यमग्रियम [29]
In the beginning as Omkara (Pranava), in the middle as Bhu-Bhuvah-Suvar etc. worlds, and in the end as the Vishwaroopa(cosmic form) I alone am. I'm the fruit of the Japa. I'm the edible and drinkable items. I'm the doable and non-doable things also. I'm the Param (supreme) and I'm the Aparam (non-supreme). I'm the sun. I'm Parayana. I'm the well being of the universe. I'm the divinity. I'm the imperishable. I'm the micro-atom (Sukshmam). I'm the Prajapatyam, holyness (Sacredness), I'm the softness (Soumya). And Agraahyam, Agriyam are also me only.

अहमेवोपसंहर्ता महाग्रासौजसां निधिः .
हृदि यो देवतात्वेन प्राणत्वेन प्रतिष्ठितः [30]
I'm the one who withdraws entire creation into myself (at the end of time), I'm the supreme light. I remain seated in the heart's core of all the creatures. I exist as Prana (soul) in the beings.

शिरश्चोत्तरतो यस्य पादौ दक्षिणतस्तथा .
यश्च सर्वोत्तरः साक्षादोङ्कारोऽहं त्रिमात्रकः [31]
ऊर्ध्वं चोन्नामहे यस्मादधश्चापनयाम्यहम .
तस्मादोङ्कार एवाहमेको नित्यः सनातनः [32]
ऋचो यजूंषि सामानि यो ब्रह्मा यज्ञअकर्मणि .
प्रणामहे ब्राह्मणेभ्यस्तेनाहं प्रणवो मतः [33]
स्नेहो यथा मांसपिण्डं व्याप्नोति व्याप्ययत्यपि .
सर्वान लोकानहं तद्वत्सर्वव्यापी ततोऽस्म्यहम [34]
ब्रह्मा हरिश्च भगवानाद्यन्तं नोपलब्धवान .
ततोऽन्ये च सुरा यस्मादनन्तोऽहमितीरितः [35]
The one whose head is towards north and whose feet remains towards south, such a supreme one, and the Pranava of three syllables (A, U, M) is none other than me. To the devotees I deliver from sins and give them upper regions, and I send the sinners to the hell. Hence I'm the ever lasting one. I'm in the form of Omkara. I'm the Rik, Yajus, and Sama Vedas as well. Through sacrifice the Brahmanas propitiate through Omkara, and that form of Pranava is me. The way flesh is an integral part of all creatures, similarly in the entire universe wholly I pervade, hence i'm the indweller of all (Sarvantaryami). Because Brahma and Vishnu failed to locate my ends, I am called to be infinite (ananta).

गर्भजन्मजरामृत्युसंसारभवसागरात .
तारयामि यतो भक्तं तस्मात्तारोऽहमीरितः [36]
चतुर्विधेषु देहेषु जीवत्वेन वसाम्यहम .
सूक्ष्मो भूत्वा च हृद्देशे यत्तत्सूक्ष्मं प्रकीर्तितः [37]
महातमसि मग्नेभ्यो भक्तेभ्यो यत्प्रकाशये .
विद्युद्वदतुलं रूपं तस्माद्विद्युतमस्म्यहम [38]
एक एव यतो लोकान विसृजामि सृजामि च .
विवासयामि गृह्णामि तस्मादेकोऽहमीश्वरः [39]
न द्वितीयो यतस्तस्थे तुरीयं ब्रह्म यत्स्वयम .
भूतान्यात्मनि संहृत्य चैको रुद्रो वसाम्यहम [40]
Because I ferry my devotees from the birth, aging, death, and liberate them from the ocean of samsaara altogether; therefore I am called as Taraka. In the four types of bodies (Jarayujam [womb born], Andajam [egg bord], Svedajam [sweat born], Udbheedam [earth born]), Because I remain in a atomic size as Jiva, hence I'm called as Sookshmarupa, To the ones who are immersed in the darkness of ignorance I show them the desire for knowledge and liberation like an electric spark hence I am called as Vaidyuta (lightening). Because I alone create universes, I alone sustain them, and again I alone take them back into myself; hence I only am called as the Eswara (Lord). There is none who is second to me because I am the Parabrahman beyond Turiya; I alone dissolve all creatures within my heart hence I am called as Rudra.

सर्वांल्लोकान्यदीशेहमीशिनीभिश्च शक्तिभिः .
ईशानमस्य जगतः स्वर्दृशं चक्षुरीश्वरम [41]
ईशानश्चास्मि जगतां सर्वेषामपि सर्वदा .
ईशानः सर्वविद्यानां यदीशानस्ततोऽस्म्यहम [42]
सर्वभावान्निरीक्षेऽहमात्मज्ञआनं निरीक्षये .
योगं च गमये तस्माद्भगवान्महतो मतः [43]
अजस्रं यच्च गृह्णामि विसृजामि सृजामि च .
सर्वांल्लोकान्वासयामि तेनाहं वै महेश्वरः [44]
महत्यात्मज्ञआनयोगैश्वर्ये यस्तु महीयते .
सर्वान भावान परित्यज्य महादेवश्च सोऽस्म्यहम [45]
Because with these many potencies I omniscient knowing everything and at the same time I remain as the means to know this universe, I am called as Jagannetra. Because I'm the lord of all creatures and all knowledge, I'm called as Eshana. Because I witness all feelings, all the Atmajnanam in time through Yoga, hence I am called as Bhagawan. I support all the worlds on me, I discard those worlds (dissolution), I create, and also I make them stay; hence for all these reasons I am called as the Supreme Lord (Maheshwara). The Mahadeva who is known by Atmajnana-Yoga, Aishwarya, O Rama! such a supreme being who is beyond Mahat- that Mahadeva is me.

एषोऽस्मि देवः प्रदिशो नु सर्वाः पूर्वो हि जातोस्म्यहमेव गर्भे .
अहं हि जातश्च जनिष्यमाणः प्रत्यग्जनस्तिष्ठति सर्वतोमुखः [46]
विश्वतश्चक्षुरुत विश्वतोमुखो विश्वतोबाहुरुत विश्वतस्पात .
संवाहुभ्यां धमति संपतत्रै- र्द्यावाभूमी जनयन्देव एकः [47]
वालाग्रमात्रं हृदयस्य मध्ये विश्वं देवं जातवेदं वरेण्यम .
मामात्मस्थं येऽनुपश्यन्ति धीरा- स्तेषां शान्तिः शाश्वती नेतरेषाम [48]
अहं योनिमधितिष्ठामि चैको मयेदं पूर्णं पञ्चविधं च सर्वम .
मामीशानं पुरुषं देवमीड्यं विदित्वा निचाय्येमां शान्तिमत्यन्तमेति [49]
प्राणेष्वन्तर्मनसो लिङ्गमाहु- रस्मिन्क्रोधोउआ च तृष्णा क्षमा च .
तृष्णां हित्वा हेतुजालस्य मूलं बुद्ध्या चित्तं स्थापयित्वा मयीह .
एवं ये मां ध्यायमाना भजंते तेषां शान्तिः शाश्वती नेतरेषाम [50]
I am the lord who is born within directions (space and time), I'm the one being born, I'm the one who is still inside the womb, I'm the old aged one, and I am the one who has faces everywhere. I'm the protector of the worlds. All faces are my faces, all eyes are my eyes, all limbs are my limbs. I am the creator of Bhu-Bhuvah-Suvar kind of worlds. Moreover people who realize me as the one dwelling in the hearts of all as a divine light, as the master and leader of all creation; such a kind of Jiva only can attain permanant peace called liberation, Others can not! I alone remain as the cause behind the creation and dwell as the inner soul of all. In this way one who knows me as Eswara, primordial being, Mahadeva, and enquires into me such a one gains liberation. The Prana which is the cause of all sensations like hunger, thirst etc. such a Prana is also I alone. One who meditates on me, and worships me such a one gains final bestitude as eternal peace. Others do not gain that.

यतो वाचो निवर्तन्ते अप्राप्य मनसा सह .
आनन्दं ब्रह्म मां ज्ञआत्वा न बिभेति कुतश्चन [51]
श्रुत्वेति देवा मद्वाक्यं कैवल्यज्ञआनमुत्तमम .
जपन्तो मम नामानि मम ध्यानपरायणाः [52]
सर्वे ते स्वस्वदेहान्ते मत्सायुज्यं गताः पुरा .
ततोऽग्रे परिदृश्यन्ते पदार्था मद्विभूतयः [53]
मय्येव सकलं जातं मयि सर्वं प्रतिष्ठितम .
मयि सर्वं लयं याति तद्ब्रह्माद्वयमस्म्यहम [54]
अणोरणीयानहमेव तद्व- न्महानहं विश्वमहं विशुद्धः .
पुरातनोऽहं पुरुषोऽहमीशो हिरण्मयोऽहं शिवरूपमस्मि [55]
अपाणिपादोऽहमचिन्त्यशक्तिः पश्याम्यचक्षुः स शृणोम्यकर्णः .
अहं विजानामि विविक्तरूपो न चास्ति वेत्ता मम चित्सदाहम [56]
The wise man who realizes me as the Satchidananda Brahman, he doesn't fear of anything. In this way the gods listened to my words and realized the path towards Kaivalyam, and thereafter they remained devoted to me through Japa of my names, through meditation and at the end of their lifespan they got Sayujyam (merged) in me. That's why whatever things are visible to your eyes all those are my forms only. Everything takes birth in me, in me only everything survives and in me only everything gets dissolved; that's the reason why I am called as Advitiya Brahman (secondless supreme Brahman). I remain in atomic form in micro elements, I remain in gross form in macro elements I am the Puranapurusha (primordial person), I am eternal, I am hiranmaya (of golden hue), I am Shiva. I don't have hands and feet but still I can grasp anything, I do not have eyes but I see everything, devoid of ears I hear everything, I remain as the ether, I am of teh form of conciousness (chit), and i am the knower of everything. However there is no one who knows me in reality.

वेदैरशेषैरहमेव वेद्यो वेदान्तकृद्वेदविदेव चाहम .
न पुण्यपापे मम नास्ति नाशो न जन्म देहेन्द्रियबुद्धिरस्ति [57]
न भूमिरापो न च वह्निरस्ति न चानिलो मेऽस्ति न मे नभश्च .
एवं विदित्वा एवं मां तत्त्वतो वेत्ति यस्तु राम महाम्ते
परमात्मरूपं गुहाशयं निष्कलमद्वितीयम [58]
समस्तसाक्षिं सदसद्विहीनः प्रयाति शुद्धं पर्मात्मरूपम [59]
एवं मां तत्त्वतो वेत्ति यस्तु राम महामते . स एव नान्य लोकेषु कैवल्यफलमश्नुते [60]
I am the one to be known through all the Vedas. I am the creator of Vedas and Vedanta. I'm the knower of Vedas. I am beyond virtues and vices. There is nothing called as 'End' to me. I am beyond birth and death. I am beyond the five elemental nature. In this way whosoever realizes me as the paramatma who is the all witnesser, who is pure, who dwells in hearts; such people only reaches me. O Rama! in this way whosoever realizes me truely, only that one would gain Kaivalya, others would not.